# SQL query - number of products assigned to attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a SQL query (MySQL database), which determines the number of products for various parameters (attributes).

I try this sql query - I simulate a selection attribute "Color black"

```
SELECT codmm.id_parameter_codebook, COUNT(codmm.id_parameter_codebook) count_products,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT prod.title ORDER BY prod.id) products_title
FROM catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm codmm
JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value pv ON pv.id=codmm.id_parameter_product_value
JOIN catalog_parameter p ON p.id=pv.id_parameter
JOIN (
  SELECT p.id, p.title
  FROM catalog_product p
  JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value pv ON p.id=pv.id_product
  JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm codmm ON pv.id=codmm.id_parameter_product_value
  JOIN catalog_parameter par ON par.id=pv.id_parameter
  WHERE (codmm.id_parameter_codebook = 19)
  GROUP BY p.id
) prod ON prod.id=pv.id_product 
GROUP BY codmm.id_parameter_codebook ORDER BY p.title
```

But the output of this query not contains attribute (color green), which is a plus 1 product.

I have this database model:
[image]

Filled data in tables:

table "catalog_parameter":

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Color |
|  3 | Width |
+----+-------+
```

table "catalog_parameter_product_value":

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  | id_product | id_parameter |
+-----+------------+--------------+
| 260 |         11 |            1 |
| 261 |         11 |            3 |
| 262 |          9 |            1 |
| 263 |          9 |            3 |
| 264 |          8 |            1 |
| 265 |          8 |            3 |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

table "catalog_product"

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   title   |
+----+-----------+
|  8 | Product 3 |
|  9 | Product 2 |
| 11 | Product 1 |
+----+-----------+
```

table "catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm":

```
+-----+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| id  | id_parameter_product_value | id_parameter_codebook |
+-----+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| 139 |                        260 |                    19 |
| 140 |                        261 |                    20 |
| 141 |                        262 |                    19 |
| 142 |                        263 |                    21 |
| 143 |                        264 |                    24 |
| 144 |                        265 |                    20 |
+-----+----------------------------+-----------------------+
```

table "catalog_parameter_codebook":

```
+----+--------------+-------+
| id | id_parameter | title |
+----+--------------+-------+
| 18 |            1 | white |
| 19 |            1 | black |
| 20 |            3 | 100   |
| 21 |            3 | 200   |
| 22 |            3 | 300   |
| 23 |            3 | 400   |
| 24 |            1 | green |
+----+--------------+-------+
```

Examples after selecting attributes:

If you do not choose any parameters (attributes), output looks like this:

```
- Color
*** black (2)
*** green (1)

- Width
*** 100 (2)
*** 200 (1)
```

If you select an attribute "Color black" I should get output

```
- Color
*** black (2) - ACTIVE
*** green (+1)

- Width
*** 100 (1)
*** 200 (1)
```

If you select an attribute "Color black" and "Width 100" I should get output

```
- Color
*** black (1) - ACTIVE
*** green (0)

- Width
*** 100 (+1)
*** 200 (1) - ACTIVE
```

If you select an attribute "Color black" a "Color green" I should get output

```
- Color
*** black (2) - ACTIVE
*** green (1) - ACTIVE

- Width
*** 100 (1)
*** 200 (1)
```

SQL Fiddle url url for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4599/2

Comment: sounds interesting, but more of an assignment for us !

Comment: Are you familiar with the GROUP BY clause of the SELECT statement?

Comment: Yes, I know  GROUP BY clause

Comment: Nice question. Please spend as much time now on solving it yourself than on posing it. Add you own best effort to the question first and people will then be glad to comment on it. Just don't expect us to get your degree for you.

Comment: I tried several options and each was poor. I need a kick

Comment: @kevas I think it would still help if you added your attempts to the question. From the [Stack Overflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.". Otherwise this question may end up getting closed.

Comment: but my attempts were totally wrong and I do not want to influence anyone

Comment: That's fine, your wrong attempts show your approach and we can perhaps tell you what is wrong about it and how to improve it. It shows part of how you were thinking about the problem before you came here.